# How do I convert a data frame with two key:value columns to a list and to JSON format in R

Tags: json, r, list, dataframe

I have a data frame that looks like this (except 10000+ rows):

```
      V1         V2
  google 0.99702575
   gmail 0.02492131
    maps 0.02040844
motorola 0.02006636
    view 0.01679274
```

I need to convert it into JSON format with toJSON(), but I first need to convert it into a list that looks like this:

```
$google
[1] 0.99702575

$gmail
[1] 0.2492131

$maps
[1] 0.02040844

$motorola
[1] 0.02006636

$view
[1] 0.01679274
```

All I would need to do at that point is toJSON(list). The end result should look like this:

```
{"google":0.99702575,"gmail":0.02492131,"maps":0.02040844,"motorola":0.02006636,"view":0.01679274}
```

How do I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a list and set names using `setNames`

```
as.list(setNames(dat$V2,dat$V1))
```

Using your data, For example:

```
dat <- read.table(text='    V1         V2
  google 0.99702575
   gmail 0.02492131
    maps 0.02040844
motorola 0.02006636
    view 0.01679274',header=TRUE)
ll <- as.list(setNames(dat$V2,dat$V1))
library(rjson)
toJSON(ll)
```

Answer (score 3):

Create a list, then set the names

```
V2 <- as.list(DF[['V2']])
names(V2) <- as.character(DF[['V1']])
# V2 is now the list you requested.
```